# Embed google spreadsheet as a table into email body

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have data in google spreadsheet (A1:B16 - sheet name "test2") and i cant figure out a script that will pull the data from the specific sheet and put it into a table in the body of an email. I would then use a time trigger to automate the process.

Answer (score 0):

Use [getValues()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/class_range#getValues) to retrieve the values of your range. Then [sendEmail()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/class_mailapp#sendEmail) to send your email.